# Looking for manual explaining GET and Inject?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, annotations

To get the GET params from an XHTML facelet I use injection. I found a code that works perfectly for doing that, but unfortunately I don't really understand the code (listed below).

Could someone point me to a good manual/documentation that explains this matter? As I don't know a lot about how the code really works, I don't really know what to look for.

ManagedPropertyInject.java:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.inject.Qualifier;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import javax.enterprise.util.Nonbinding;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface ManagedPropertyInject {
    @Nonbinding String value() default "";
}
```

ManagedPropertyProducer.java:

```
import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.el.ExpressionFactory;
import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.faces.application.Application;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class ManagedPropertyProducer {
    @Produces @ManagedPropertyInject @Dependent
    public String getStringManagedPropertyInject(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return (String) getObjectManagedPropertyInject(injectionPoint, String.class);
    }

    private Object getObjectManagedPropertyInject(InjectionPoint injectionPoint, Class expectedType) {
        String value = injectionPoint.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(ManagedPropertyInject.class).value();
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Application application = context.getApplication();
        ExpressionFactory ef = application.getExpressionFactory();
        ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();
        ValueExpression ve = ef.createValueExpression(elContext, value, expectedType);
        return ve.getValue(elContext);
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
@Inject
@ManagedPropertyInject("#{param.language}")
private String language;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getStringManagedPropertyInject` is a producer for strings that are injected with a qualifier `@ManagedPropertyInject`. That is the case for your example use. So the attribute language will receive the value returned by the method `getStringManagedPropertyInject`.

For the details that follow I used only the javadoc.

```
String value = injectionPoint.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(ManagedPropertyInject.class).value();
```

get the value of the annotation at the injection point; here `#{param.language}`.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();`
Application application = context.getApplication();
ExpressionFactory ef = application.getExpressionFactory();
```

get the expression factory used to calculate an EL expression.

```
ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();
ValueExpression ve = ef.createValueExpression(elContext, value, expectedType);
```

(from javadoc:) Parses an expression into a ValueExpression for later evaluation. Use this method for expressions that refer to values. expectedype is String because the value will be a String.

```
return ve.getValue(elContext);
```

return  the value of `#{param.language}` in the context. param is a predifined object of the expression language. It is a map of HTTP request parameters. So you get the value of the language parameter.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining. Slowly I start to understand it.